# How to increment numbers on the end of variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a Python/Tkinter program and I am trying to increment some numbers that are at the end of a variable used for tk.Entry boxes.

For example, self.output0, self.output1, self.output2, etc

(Sorry, my code is long so I tried shortening it up for an example.)

```
    self.entries = []
    self.output0 = tk.Entry(self, width=149, justify='center', bd='0', bg='#E0E0E0')
    self.output0.grid(column=0, row=6, columnspan=5, padx=1)

    self.output1 = tk.Entry(self, width=149, justify='center', bd='0', bg='#E0E0E0')
    self.output1.grid(column=0, row=7, columnspan=5, padx=1)
```

I grab the users input with another entry box such as 'self.first_entry' and run a SQL query on the user input.

For example:

```
class Adder(ttk.Frame):
    """The adders gui and functions."""
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = parent
        self.init_gui()

    def authenticate(self):
        return pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=MYSERVERNAME;Database=MYDATABASENAME;Trusted_Connection=yes;')

    def calculate(self):
        firstname = str(self.first_entry.get()) # converts user entry into variable
        lastname = str(self.last_entry.get())     
        license = str(self.lic_entry.get())

        try:
            connection = self.authenticate()
        except pypyodbc.Error as ex:
            sqlstate = ex.args[0]
            if sqlstate == '28000':
                self.output0.delete(0, END)
                self.output0.insert(0,"You do not have access.") 
        cursor = connection.cursor() 
        if (firstname and not lastname and not license):  # "You entered first name."
            SQLCommand = ("SELECT LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, LICNUMBER "      
                "FROM MyTABLEName "   # table name
                "with (nolock)"
                "WHERE FIRSTNAME LIKE ?")
            Values = [firstname + '%']
        else:
            SQLCommand = ("SELECT LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, LICNUMBER "      
                "FROM MyTABLEName "   # table name
                "(nolock)"
                "WHERE FIRSTNAME LIKE ? AND LASTNAME LIKE ? AND LICNUMBER LIKE ?")
            Values = [firstname + '%', lastname + '%', '%' + license + '%']
        cursor.execute(SQLCommand,Values)
        results = cursor.fetchmany(10)
        if results:
            self.output0.delete(0, END)  # clears entry
            self.output0.insert(0,results[0]) # enters results in entry
            self.output1.delete(0, END)  # clears entry
            self.output1.insert(0,results[1]) # enters results in entry
            self.output2.delete(0, END)  # clears entry
            self.output2.insert(0,results[2]) # enters results in entry
            self.output3.delete(0, END)  # clears entry
            self.output3.insert(0,results[3]) # enters results in entry
            self.output4.delete(0, END)  # clears entry
            self.output4.insert(0,results[4]) # enters results in entry
            connection.close()
        else:
            self.output0.delete(0, END)
            self.output0.insert(0,"There are no records for this input.")
```

The above will output 5 rows from the database.

I am wanting to shorten the code up.  How can I take the below and write it so that I do not have to repeat

```
            self.output0.delete(0, END)  # clears entry
            self.output0.insert(0,results[0]) # enters results in entry
            self.output1.delete(0, END)  # clears entry
            self.output1.insert(0,results[1]) # enters results in entry
            2
            2
            3
            3
            ...etc
```

I want to increment the outputX and the number in results[x]

This below is what I have been trying but it is not working:

```
    results = cursor.fetchmany(10)
    i = 0
    myDelete = (self.output%d.delete(0, END) % (i))
    myInsert = (sef.output%d.insert(0,results[0]) % (i))

    if results:
        for int(i) in myDelete, myInsert (i):
            i += 0
            print (myDelete)  # clears entry
            print (myInsert)  # enters results in entry
        connection.close()
    else:
            self.output0.delete(0, END)
            self.output0.insert(0,"There are no records for this input.")
```

Right now I am getting a "Can't assign to function call" error but I am not even sure if I am going about this the right way.

Comment: You could add an output dictionary to the class, self.outputDict[0] = self.output0, self.outputDict[1] = self.output1 ...  self.outputDict[n] = self.outputN ... then you could iterate through the dictionary to process the results.

Comment: store your widgets in a list or dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

You could add all the outputs to a list:

```
self.outputs = [self.output0, self.output1, self.output2] #etc...
```

And then loop through them:

```
for output in self.outputs:
    output.delete(0, END) #etc...
```

You can even create outputs like such:

```
self.outputs = []

for i in range(4):
   output = tk.Entry(
       self, width=149, justify='center', bd='0', bg='#E0E0E0'
   )
   output.grid(column=0, row=6, columnspan=5, padx=1) 
   self.outputs.append(output)
```

Though you would need to add a way to change the row number and whatever else needs to be different for each iteration.